# How can I set conditional child task to continue or pause based on status (success/failure/warning) of a parent task in SnowFlake data warehouse?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Currently evaluating Snowflake database for our data warehouse, based on their documentation, Looks like Snowflake do have support for scheduling [Tasks](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro) and create task tree hierarchy.

Snowflake does seem to support conditional child task but I can't figure out setting up a conditional task to continue or pause child task based on parent task success/warning or failure.

```
## Sample Task tree creation in Snowflake

// Create a child task
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK DATA_IMPORT
WAREHOUSE = COMPUTE_WH
SCHEDULE = ‘60 MINUTE’

AS
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS2 SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS;

// Create a child task
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK DATA_IMPORT
WAREHOUSE = COMPUTE_WH
WHEN 1=2  // SAMPLE CONDITION
AFTER DATA_IMPORT
AS
CALL POST_PROCESS_STORED_PROCEDURE( );
```

Would appreciate any pointers if you have more knowledge on Snowflake Task structure.
Thank you

Comment: Haven't tried but it would be great to check condition based on parent task history.

Answer (score 1):

[CREATE TASK](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task):

> AFTER string [ , string , ... ]
>
> Specifies one or more predecessor tasks for the current task. Use this option to create a DAG of tasks or add this task to an existing DAG. A DAG is a series of tasks that starts with a scheduled root task and is linked together by dependencies.
>
> **A task runs after all of its predecessor tasks have finished their own runs successfully (after a brief lag).**
>
> ---
>
> [CREATE TASK - Examples](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task#examples)
>
> ...
>
> **The child task runs only after all specified predecessor tasks have successfully completed their own runs.**

Comment: With this setting, is it possible to continue child tasks even if there are errors in parent task?

Comment: We cannot continue if parent is in error.